# SQL, Update a table with Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I built a cursor to read records from the People table.
I would like to compare the existing email address in the contacts table (saved under info) with the email addresses in the people table and create a person reference(refperson in the contacts table) based on the email address from Contacts.

In the person table are 3 different email addresses  possible: eMail, Email2, Email3.

The update only occurs if I compare the email address from the contacts table with one value from the people table(not all 3 emails).
I tried to combine the 3 conditions in a where clause, but the references are still not created.

Where is the mistake?

```
DECLARE @id uniqueidentifier, @email nvarchar(max), @email2 nvarchar(max),  @email3 nvarchar(max), @reffirma uniqueidentifier;
  
DECLARE cur_refperson CURSOR FOR   
select p.ID, p.eMail,p.Email2, p.Email3,p.RefFirma
from Personen p
INNER JOIN Kontakte k
ON k.RefPerson=k.ID
OPEN cur_refperson

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_refperson
INTO @id,@email,@email2,@email3,@reffirma

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
    
    UPDATE Kontakte
    SET RefPerson=@id,RefFirma=@reffirma
    WHERE (CONVERT(nvarchar,Info)=@email)
    OR (CONVERT(nvarchar,Info)=@email2)
    OR (CONVERT(nvarchar,Info)=@email3)

    Fetch Next from cur_refperson INTO  @id,@email,@email2, @email3,@reffirma

    END
CLOSE cur_refperson;
DEALLOCATE cur_refperson;
```

Comment: I would ask why are you using a `CURSOR` at all and not a set based solution.

Comment: Strongly suspect it is due to you didn't specify the size for `nvarchar` in `CONVERT()`. What is the data type and size for column `Info` ?

Comment: @Eichhörnchen I specified the size, unfortunately that's not the reason. The data type of Info is text.

Comment: You don't specify the size in the code above, @Eszter , you implicitly define an `nvarchar(30)` (and many email addresses are longer than that), which when you define the variables as being `MAX` in length (so likely to be longer than 4,000 characters) there's certainly some mismatching in lengths going on there (though email address can't be 4,000 characters in length, so the use of `MAX` is odd too).

Comment: @Larna thanks. I just put the size down after it was recommended to me. I don't define nvarchar(30) anywhere so you must have missed something. I'm an intern so I'm having trouble and a lot of things that make sense to you are mine unfortunately not quite clear yet.

Comment: *"I don't define nvarchar(30) anywhere so you must have missed something."* It's not I that is missing something, it's you, you do **implicitly** define an `nvarchar(30)`, as @Squirrel said too: `CONVERT(nvarchar,Info)` = `CONVERT(nvarchar(30),Info)` See [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: @Larnu I just modified the code, changed the size to nvarchar(70) and everything is working now.
Thanks for the help , I am very happy.:-)

Comment: I still suggest getting the code fixed to be a set based solution.

Comment: Your cursor query does not make sense. `INNER JOIN Kontakte k ON k.RefPerson=k.ID`.  Is it supposed to join to `p.ID`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue is almost certainly due to the fact that you did not specify a length for `nvarchar` in the `CONVERT`. You should have had `CONVERT(nvarchar(250), Info)` or similar

However, there should be no need to specify this conversion anyway, as SQL Server will automatically widen to `nvarchar` in any case.

Furthermore, the whole cursor is unnecessary. You should just do a normal joined update. The join condition is not entirely clear, but it seems it is `k.Info IN (p.email, p.email2, p.email3)`

```sql
UPDATE k
SET RefPerson = p.ID,
    RefFirma= p.RefFirma
FROM Kontakte k
JOIN Personen p ON k.Info IN (p.email, p.email2, p.email3);
```